# Open existing file, append a single line

Tags: c#, file

I want to open a text file, append a single line to it, then close it.

Answer (score 453, accepted):

You can use [`File.AppendAllText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143356.aspx) for that:

```
File.AppendAllText(@"c:\path\file.txt", "text content" + Environment.NewLine);
```

Answer (score 158):

```
using (StreamWriter w = File.AppendText("myFile.txt"))
{
  w.WriteLine("hello");
}
```

Comment: This is the proper way to write to a file is you are generating a lot of lines, to avoid memory issues.

Answer (score 95):

Choice one! But the first is very simple. The last maybe util for file manipulation:

```
//Method 1 (I like this)
File.AppendAllLines(
    "FileAppendAllLines.txt", 
    new string[] { "line1", "line2", "line3" });

//Method 2
File.AppendAllText(
    "FileAppendAllText.txt",
    "line1" + Environment.NewLine +
    "line2" + Environment.NewLine +
    "line3" + Environment.NewLine);

//Method 3
using (StreamWriter stream = File.AppendText("FileAppendText.txt"))
{
    stream.WriteLine("line1");
    stream.WriteLine("line2");
    stream.WriteLine("line3");
}

//Method 4
using (StreamWriter stream = new StreamWriter("StreamWriter.txt", true))
{
    stream.WriteLine("line1");
    stream.WriteLine("line2");
    stream.WriteLine("line3");
}

//Method 5
using (StreamWriter stream = new FileInfo("FileInfo.txt").AppendText())
{
    stream.WriteLine("line1");
    stream.WriteLine("line2");
    stream.WriteLine("line3");
}
```

Answer (score 12):

Or you could use [`File.AppendAllLines(string, IEnumerable<string>)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383691(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
File.AppendAllLines(@"C:\Path\file.txt", new[] { "my text content" });
```

Answer (score 4):

The technically best way is probably this here:

```cs
private static async Task AppendLineToFileAsync([NotNull] string path, string line)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(path)) 
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(path), path, "Was null or whitepsace.");

    if (!File.Exists(path)) 
        throw new FileNotFoundException("File not found.", nameof(path));

    using (var file = File.Open(path, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write))
    using (var writer = new StreamWriter(file))
    {
        await writer.WriteLineAsync(line);
        await writer.FlushAsync();
    }
}
```

Comment: Only option to not throw an error if called in rapid succession

Answer (score 3):

Might want to check out the [TextWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.textwriter.aspx) class.

```
//Open File
TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter("file.txt");

//Write to file
tw.WriteLine("test info");

//Close File
tw.Close();
```

Comment: It replaces the current content with new text

Answer (score 2):

File.AppendText will do it:

```
using (StreamWriter w = File.AppendText("textFile.txt")) 
{
    w.WriteLine ("-------HURRAY----------");
    w.Flush();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use

```cs
public StreamWriter(string path, bool append);
```

while opening the file

```cs
string path="C:\\MyFolder\\Notes.txt"
StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(path, true);
```

First parameter is a string to hold a full file path
Second parameter is Append Mode, that in this case is made true

Writing to the file can be done with:

`writer.Write(string)`

or

`writer.WriteLine(string)`

**Sample Code**

```
private void WriteAndAppend()
{
            string Path = Application.StartupPath + "\\notes.txt";
            FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(Path);
            StreamWriter SW;
            StreamReader SR;
            if (fi.Exists)
            {
                SR = new StreamReader(Path);
                string Line = "";
                while (!SR.EndOfStream) // Till the last line
                {
                    Line = SR.ReadLine();
                }
                SR.Close();
                int x = 0;
                if (Line.Trim().Length <= 0)
                {
                    x = 0;
                }
                else
                {
                    x = Convert.ToInt32(Line.Substring(0, Line.IndexOf('.')));
                }
                x++;
                SW = new StreamWriter(Path, true);
                SW.WriteLine("-----"+string.Format("{0:dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm:ss tt}", DateTime.Now));
                SW.WriteLine(x.ToString() + "." + textBox1.Text);

            }
            else
            {
                SW = new StreamWriter(Path);
                SW.WriteLine("-----" + string.Format("{0:dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm:ss tt}", DateTime.Now));
                SW.WriteLine("1." + textBox1.Text);
            }
            SW.Flush();
            SW.Close();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//display sample reg form in notepad.txt
using (StreamWriter stream = new FileInfo("D:\\tt.txt").AppendText())//ur file location//.AppendText())
{
   stream.WriteLine("Name :" + textBox1.Text);//display textbox data in notepad
   stream.WriteLine("DOB : " + dateTimePicker1.Text);//display datepicker data in notepad
   stream.WriteLine("DEP:" + comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString());
   stream.WriteLine("EXM :" + listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString());
}
```