# Write data from Textbox into text file in ASP.net with C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, writetofile

I have a textbox where a user can input their email, what I want to do is make it so that when they click a submit button. That email will be saved into a text file ( on my server ) called emails.txt

I managed to get this working using System.IO and then using the File.WriteAll method. However I want to make it so that it will add the email to the list ( on a new line ) rather then just overwriting whats already in there.

I've seen people mention using Append, but I can't quite grasp how to get it working.

This is my current code (that overwrites instead of appending).

```
public partial class _Default : Page
{
    private string path = null;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        path = Server.MapPath("~/emails.txt");
    }

    protected void emailButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        File.WriteAllText(path, emailTextBox.Text.Trim());
        confirmEmailLabel.Text = "Thank you for subscribing";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [StreamWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter.aspx) to get working with text file. The `WriteLine` method in `true` mode append your email in new line each time....

```
using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("email.txt", true)) //// true to append data to the file
{
    writer.WriteLine("your_data"); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From the official [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3zc0w663.aspx):

```
using (StreamWriter w = File.AppendText("log.txt"))
{
   MyWriteFunction("Test1", w);
   MyWriteFunction("Test2", w);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `StreamWriter` in Append mode. Write your data with `WriteLine(data)`.

```
using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("emails.txt", true))
{
    writer.WriteLine(email);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a very easy question with a very easy answer: [Open existing file, append a single line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2837020/open-existing-file-append-a-single-line)

If you post the current code, we can modify that to append instead of overwrite.