# how to corrupt sql server backup database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, backup, restore, corruption

I want to corrupt sql server database backup in order to test some thing on sql server.

I open backup file in notepad and clean some data from it.

Does anyone have better solution?

Some time backup file is huge and I can't open it in notepad.

Comment: Banned on Google? You need this query: Windows hex editor.

Answer (score 0):

You can download UltraEdit and use the trial version to edit large files. That would be the only way I know of.

Answer (score 0):

Notepad is horrible at big files.  Use notepad++.

Or write a small c# app to open the file, read the bytes and somewhere in the middle, write some random bytes.

Similar to this:
[Open existing file, append a single line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2837020/open-existing-file-append-a-single-line)

Answer (score 0):

Could start at source and create a corrupt database, then backup that database.
http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/CheckDB/88963/