# C# move to end of file with StreamWriter created from FileStream

Tags: c#, filestream

I need to create a StreamWriter from a FileStream object and append some text to 
the file. It is assumed that the FileStream object that is being used has been created with FileMode.OpenOrCreate and FileAccess.ReadWrite. I have:

```
using (FileStream fs = GetCurrentFileStream())
{
    StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs);
    sw.WriteLine("StringToAppend");
    sw.Flush();
}
```

However this just overwrites the file from the beginning. How do I move to the end of the file? Is there perhaps a way to change the FileMode to Append and FileAccess to Write after the FileStream has been created?

Edit: As mentioned above I need to do this using a FileStream object. The answers from [Open existing file, append a single line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2837020/open-existing-file-append-a-single-line) assume that I can create a new StreamWriter from the file path which I don't have.

Edit 2: Added truncated version of GetCurrentFileStream().

```
    public static FileStream GetCurrentFileStream()
    {
        String fileName = getFileName();
        FileStream fs = OpenFileWhenAvailable(fileName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.None);
    }

    public static FileStream OpenFileWhenAvailable(String fileName, FileMode fileMode, FileAccess fileAccess, FileShare fileShare)
    {
        int tries = 0;
        int timeout = 10 * 1000;
        while (true)
        {
            tries++;
            try
            {
                return new FileStream(fileName, fileMode, fileAccess, fileShare);
            }
            catch (IOException ex)
            {
                if (tries * 100 > timeout)
                {
                    return null;
                }
                else
                {
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

GetCurrentFileStream is used in several different contexts, so changing the FileMode and FileAccess directly is not an option. I do not wish to make a separate version of GetCurrentFileStream just for this one case, which is why I'm asking if there is a way to jump to the end of the stream and append a string when the FileStream object has already been created.

Comment: Not the same. I need to do it from an existing FileStream object.

Comment: Try `fs.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.End)` before `sw.WriteLine`.

Comment: In addition to what @MarkShevchenko said, `Seek` *before* you create the `StreamWriter`. Seeking an underlying stream is undocumented behavior and it could break in the future, regardless of the fact that it works at the moment.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you want to append your line to a created file:

```
using (FileStream fs = GetCurrentFileStream())
{
    StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs, true);
    sw.WriteLine("StringToAppend");
    sw.Flush();
}
```

With this overload of the StreamWriter constructor you choose if you append the file, or overwrite it.

It will be really cool if you show your implementation of method `GetCurrentStream()`:

```
using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(fileName,FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write))
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs))
{
   sw.WriteLine(something);
}
```

**Update**:

```
using (FileStream fs = GetCurrentFileStream())
{
   StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs);
   long endPoint=fs.Length;
   // Set the stream position to the end of the file.        
   fs.Seek(endPoint, SeekOrigin.Begin);
   sw.WriteLine("StringToAppend");
   sw.Flush();
 }
```

Comment: The parameter `bool append` is not available when constructing the StreamWriter from a FileStream. As for GetCurrentStream(), it's part of a loop that finds the filenames for files that needs to be modified based on an algorithm and then performs a try in a loop to lock the file as soon as it is available as there will be several processes trying to access the files. Furthermore the operation of appending to the file is not always going to be performed, other times reading the file or doing both read and write are necessary. Returning a FileStream object leaves more options for what to do.

Comment: @EJS more code, please. Show GetCurrentFileStream().

Comment: Added truncated version of GetCurrentFileStream(). I think the interesting part will be the part where the FileStream parameters are set to `(fileName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.None)`.

Comment: @EJS so try to set necessary parameters at your constructor as shown in the second example. Let me know if you have trouble with this and I can try to help further.

Comment: As I explained in the edit I can't directly change the parameters as this would make the method fail in other contexts. I will add a condition at the top of my question to take this into consideration.

Comment: Thanks! Works. Exactly what I was looking for:)

Comment: @EJS you can sign my answer as an answer to your question. It will help to  people who meet your condition.

Answer (score -1):

If you really really wanted to, you could pretty this up....

```
    static int iMaxLogLength = 15000;
    static int iTrimmedLogLength = -2000;

    static public void writeToFile2(string strMessage, string strLogFileDirectory, int iLogLevel)
    {
        string strFile = strLogFileDirectory + "log.log";

        try
        {
            FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(strFile);

            Byte[] bytesRead = null;

            if (fi.Length > iMaxLogLength)
            {
                using (BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(File.Open(strFile, FileMode.Open)))
                {
                    // Go to the end of the file and backup some
                    br.BaseStream.Seek(iTrimmedLogLength, SeekOrigin.End);

                    // Read that.
                    bytesRead = br.ReadBytes((-1 * iTrimmedLogLength));
                }
            }

            byte[] newLine = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Environment.NewLine);

            FileStream fs = null;
            if (fi.Length < iMaxLogLength)
                fs = new FileStream(strFile, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Read);
            else
                fs = new FileStream(strFile, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Read);

            using (fs)
            {
                if (bytesRead != null)
                {
                    fs.Write(bytesRead, 0, bytesRead.Length);
                    fs.Write(newLine, 0, newLine.Length);
                    Byte[] lineBreak = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("### " + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") + " *** *** *** New Log Start Position *** *** *** *** ###");
                    fs.Write(lineBreak, 0, lineBreak.Length);
                    fs.Write(newLine, 0, newLine.Length);
                }
                Byte[] sendBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(strMessage);
                fs.Write(sendBytes, 0, sendBytes.Length);
                fs.Write(newLine, 0, newLine.Length);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ; // Write to event or something
        }
    }
```