# How do I use Streamwriter to write my code on a new line

Tags: c#, winforms, streamwriter

Hi I need to create a list in .txt but using these codes I am only able to write data and keying anymore will just overwrite the first one

```
        int score = Convert.ToInt32(ScoreLBL.Text);
        String name = NameTB.Text;
        List<Leaderboard> LB = new List<Leaderboard>();
        Leaderboard results;

        results = new Leaderboard(name, score);
        LB.Add(results);


        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\zxong\Desktop\EGL138-OBJECT-ORIENTED PROGRAMMING\Project\Leaderboard.txt");
        for (int i = 0; i< LB.Count(); i++)
        {
            sw.WriteLine(LB[i].getName() + "," + LB[i].getScore());                
        }
```

Leaderboard class

```
    class Leaderboard
    {
    private String name;
    protected int score;

    public Leaderboard(String n, int s)
    {
        this.name = n;
        this.score = s;
    }

    public String getName()
    {
        return this.name;
    }

    public int getScore()
    {
        return this.score;
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C# move to end of file with StreamWriter created from FileStream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33671428/c-sharp-move-to-end-of-file-with-streamwriter-created-from-filestream)

Comment: you might also just use [File.AppendText](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.appendtext?view=net-6.0)

Comment: [StreamWriter(String, Boolean)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamwriter.-ctor?view=net-6.0#system-io-streamwriter-ctor(system-string-system-boolean))

Comment: Tried both methods but didn't work. Instead of having 1 line of name,score , I got line1: name and line2: name,score

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. The code you've given would never write only a single value on a line. As an aside, I'd very strongly advise you to start following .NET naming conventions.

Answer (score 1):

i think this small change should be able to give you the functionality you want:

```
List<Leaderboard> LB = new List<Leaderboard>();

LB.Add(new Leaderboard("SomeName", 10));
LB.Add(new Leaderboard("AnotherName", 20));
LB.Add(new Leaderboard("ThirdName", 30));

using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\zxong\Desktop\EGL138-OBJECT-ORIENTED PROGRAMMING\Project\Leaderboard.txt", true)) {
   for (int i = 0; i < LB.Count; i++) {
      //Console.WriteLine(LB[i].getName() + "," + LB[i].getScore());
      sw.WriteLine(LB[i].getName() + "," + LB[i].getScore());
   }
}
```

Adding the true flag at the end of the StreamWriter should set the stream writer to work in append mode, which should add new lines rather than overwrite them on the file.

Comment: I've tried adding true but my output will instead be line1: score line2: name, score. Thanks for helping though

Comment: That looks more like an issue with the data rather than the functionality, can you add this line bore the sw.WriteLine "Console.WriteLine(LB[i].getName() + "," + LB[i].getScore());" and see if that matches what you get on yout file? assuming this is a console app

Comment: Could you try the code as shown above and see if the file builds as expected? I added some test data to allow for easy validation of the write functionality