# Write a new line of code every time the program enters a new string to the file C#

Tags: c#

```
Console.WriteLine("What name would you like to be known as?");
string usernameforscore = Console.ReadLine();
string path = *filepath*;
File.WriteAllText(path, (usernameforscore + " " + classicscore + Environment.NewLine));
```

So this code is part of a game I'm making for a project, at the end of the game when you fail, I want it to save both a person's chosen username and their score (a variable saved somewhere else). I have got it to save the two to the file, however each time someone enters a new set of data, the file is overridden and only the new data is displayed.

I would like it to write a line with the name and score, then next time the code is run, it will display the new name and score on the next line, creating a high score list.

I'm using visual studio with a console program on C#

Apologies if this is a duplicate, couldn't seem to find a fix myself.

Comment: See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.appendalltext?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: Do you create a new `File` object in your code every time ?

Comment: Instead I'd read the file and create some kind of data structure to store it, the once the game is over you can order the list based on score and write it to the file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Open existing file, append a single line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2837020/open-existing-file-append-a-single-line)

Comment: It's not a duplicate, well not really as AppendAllText wont fix OPs issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a method AppendAllText() rather than WriteAllText(), as below:

```
File.AppendAllText(@"c:\Path\filename.txt", "the text to append" + Environment.NewLine);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the below method `UpdateTextFile` to save data to a text file.

```
public static void UpdateTextFile(string fileName, string content, bool doNotOverwrite = true, bool writeNewLine = true)
{
    StreamWriter file = null;
    using (file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"D:\" + fileName + ".txt", doNotOverwrite))
    {
       if (writeNewLine)
       {
          file.WriteLine(content);
       }
       else 
          file.Write(content);

       file.Close();
    }
}
```

Example of calling the method:

```
UpdateTextFile("FileName", "file-content", true, false);
```

Hope it helps.