# How can I write text to a text file? It's overwriting the same line instead adding a new one

Tags: c#

```
for (int i = 0; i < clipAnimations.Length; i++)
{
    clipAnimations[i].name = "magic_" + name;
    string n = clipAnimations[i].name + Environment.NewLine;
    File.WriteAllText(@"d:\test\names.txt", n);
}
```

I added Environment.NewLine but still in the end I see only one line.

Comment: Use [File.AppendText](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.appendtext?view=netframework-4.7.2) instead. See, for instance, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2837020/1364007).

Comment: Do not write to file the way you do. Opening and closing file each time for a single line is not a good practice. See answer from Abhinav Bhandari.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `File.AppendText` instead. At the moment, you are using `File.WriteAllText` which creates the file if it doesn't exist, otherwise clears the existing file before writing the string to it. `File.AppendText`, however, creates the file if it doesn't exist (does not clear it if it does exist, unlike `File.WriteAllText`) and then appends the string to the end of the file.

```
using (StreamWriter w = File.AppendText(@"d:\test\names.txt"))
{
    for (int i = 0; i < clipAnimations.Length; i++)
    {
        clipAnimations[i].name = "magic_" + name;
        string n = clipAnimations[i].name; // no need to append Environment.NewLine
        w.WriteLine(n);
    }
}
```

You should also consider using  a `StreamWriter` in a `using` block as shown as this avoids opening and closing the file multiple times.

*Edit:* since the `WriteLine` method is used here, which handles line endings for you, you don't need to append Environment.NewLine to the string. Thanks @Julo !

Answer (score 1):

Use `File.AppendText()`, `WriteText()` creates a new file or overwrites an existing one whereas appending will create a new file or append to an existing one.