# Adding a new line of text to an existing file in c#

Tags: c#

I would like to add a new line consist of text but my problem is that it deleted the existing file and replace the new line that I added, here's my code:

```
        string[] data = new string[2];
        data[0]=username_txt.Text;
        data[1]=password_txt.Text;
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"database.txt");
        string oldatat=sr.ReadLine();
        sr.Close(); 

        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"database.txt");
        sw.WriteLine(data[0]+" "+data[1]+Environment.NewLine+oldatat+);
        sw.Close();
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Open existing file, append a single line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2837020/open-existing-file-append-a-single-line)

Answer (score -1):

Open file in append mode and Refer this link
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.appendtext?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: This is a link to an answer, not an answer. See [answer], the section headed "Provide context for links". But do note that this question has been asked before. Please do some research to find previous questions that ask the same thing, and flag them rather than answering.

Comment: Got yr point, I replied from mobile thats why it happened. My intention was to help user.

Comment: Would've mad a reasonable comment...