# How do you update a text file in c# without getting rid of the existing content?

Tags: c#, input, file-io

I would just like to write to a text file without the content that is already on the text file being overwritten.

```
string record = txtBxNumber.Text.PadRight(30) + txtBxDate.Text.PadRight(30)  + 
                txtBxPurchasedFrom.Text.PadRight(30) + txtBxShipTo.Text.PadRight(30) + 
                richTxBxDesc.Text.PadRight(30) + txtBxOrdered.Text.PadRight(30) + 
                txtBxUnit.Text.PadRight(30) + txtBxUnitPrice.Text.PadRight(30);

richTxtBxRecord.Text += record + "\n";
```

Then as a bonus, if possible. I'd like to update a line in the text file depending on the value of txtNumber.Text.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Open existing file, append a single line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2837020/open-existing-file-append-a-single-line)

Answer (score 0):

This is how you append text to a existing text file, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.writealltext?view=netcore-3.1 :

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;

class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string path = @"c:\temp\MyTest.txt";

        // This text is added only once to the file.
        if (!File.Exists(path))
        {
            // Create a file to write to.
            string createText = "Hello and Welcome" + Environment.NewLine;
            File.WriteAllText(path, createText);
        }

        // This text is always added, making the file longer over time
        // if it is not deleted.
        string appendText = "This is extra text" + Environment.NewLine;
        File.AppendAllText(path, appendText);

        // Open the file to read from.
        string readText = File.ReadAllText(path);
        Console.WriteLine(readText);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
File.AppendAllText(@"c:\path\file.txt", "text content" + Environment.NewLine);
```

Comment: Although this code might solve the problem, a good answer should also explain **what** the code does and **how** it helps.

Comment: @BDL I'd say "File Append All Text" is quite self explanatory..