# how to save details in "ListView" and load it in (properties settings)

Tags: c#, winforms

i have problem on ListVeiw i can't find any video talk about save listveiw in properties settings, i have a lot of ways to save details but indirect ways and weak methods

note: i don't want to use (split = "|") because if i put some details have | it broke all thing `alltext = SR.ReadToEnd().Split('|');`

im using visual studio windows forms C#

here the code

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        string[] alltext;
        string text;

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            StreamReader SR = new StreamReader("Text.txt");
            alltext = SR.ReadToEnd().Split('|');
            foreach (string s in alltext)
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s))
                {
                    listView1.Items.Add(s);
                }
            }
            SR.Close();

        }

        private void Set_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            listView1.Items.Add(textBox1.Text);


            // here save old details
            StreamReader SR = new StreamReader("Text.txt");
            text = SR.ReadToEnd();
            SR.Close();

            // Real Save details
            StreamWriter SW = new StreamWriter("Text.txt");
            SW.Write(text + textBox1.Text + "|");
            SW.Close();

            textBox1.Clear();
        }

        private void Remove_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (MessageBox.Show("do you want to remove list" , "Test" , MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel , MessageBoxIcon.Question) == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                File.WriteAllText("Text.txt", "");
                listView1.Items.Clear();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: What is going on with those timers?  Not sure why you have them.  How you save your list items is up to you.  There is no standard way.  It all depends upon your needs.  Could be as simple as using a line break to separate each data item.  You don't need to read the entire file to just save a new item.  You could just [Append](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2837020/719186) an item.

Comment: timer1 for i can see x++ .
timer2 check if x == list count or no, if is it then will stop timer2

Comment: If you don't want to use a pipe use a vertical tab, maybe. In the end a ll Items boil down to `object`so you need some custom transformation code. - The use of the timers seems both brittle and weird..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a custom class to save the items data like this:

```
    public class ItemData
    {
        public int Index { get; set; }

        public string Text { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    }
```

You can put additional information in the class if you need. Create a list of `ItemData` as a field in your form like this:

```
private List<ItemData> itemsData = new();
```

Then each time you add an item to the list add it and to the collection like this:

```
var item = listView1.Items.Add(textBox1.Text);
this.itemsData.Add(new ItemData { Index = item.Index, Text = item.Text });
```

When you need to save all the items you can convert the collection to JSON string like this:

```
string jsonString = JsonSerializer.Serialize(this.itemsData);
```

Then save the result where you need. When you need to fill the items you can get the string and convert it back to collection and fill the ListView like this:

```
List<ItemData> itemsData = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<ItemData>>(jsonString);
itemsData.ForEach(item => this.listView1.Items.Add(item.Text));
```